# Partition Numbering and PDF Bookmark Generation

Tags: sectioning, numbering, bookmarks

I'm trying to figure out how to manage the interaction of numbering features of various document parts, e.g., parts, chapters, sections, etc. and the bookmarks generated for a PDF document.

First, the number of document partition is only showing up for parts in the bookmarks. The numbers of chapters and section are not part of the names that are displayed. Is there a way to fix this?

Also, I've noticed that if a partition is not numbered (e.g., an unnumbered subsection) it doesn't show up as a bookmark. I would like to be able to have unnumbered subsections, for example, but still have them show up as bookmarks. Is there a way to do this?

To be clear on what I want to achieve, consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\part{A} %Shows up as a bookmark named "I A"; this is fine
    \chapter{B} %Shows up as a bookmark named "B"; what I want is "1 B"
      \section{C} %Shows up as a bookmark named "C"; what I want is "1.1 C"
        \subsection*{D} %Doesn't show up as bookmark; what I want is "D"
  \part{E} %Shows up as a bookmark named "II B"; this is fine
    \chapter{F} %Shows up as bookmark named "F"; what I want is "2 F"
    %...and so on
\end{document}
```

Comment: The [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) allows you to have "free reign" over what is bookmarked/not and at different levels - and its functionality forms part of the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), if you're already using it. Would you be able to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with some detail on what should be included/not and how. On a related note, the `secnumdepth` counter has an impact on what is displayed in the ToC (and also the PDF bookmarks).

Comment: @Werner I've been looking at the bookmark package but maybe I'm overlooking a relevant part of the documentation. I will try to make my question more detailed so that it's clear what is happening and what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've added an answer that is very generic and references some of the usages of the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark). Let me know if this solves your problem. If not, as you mentioned, give more detail.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) already<sup>*</sup>, the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) states:

> Usually `hyperref` automatically adds bookmarks for `\section` and similar macros. But they can also set manually.

The manual setting is performed using

```
\pdfbookmark[<level>]{<text>}{<name>}
```

where `\part` is level `-1`, `\chapter` is level `0`, `\section` is level `1`, ... It places `<text>` in the bookmarks and can be referenced internally (via a hyperlink) as `<name>`. Or, if you want to place it at a level relative to the current one, use

```
\currentpdfbookmark{<text>}{<name>}
\subpdfbookmark{<text>}{<name>}
\belowpdfbookmark{<text>}{<name>}
```

where `<text>` and `<name>` have similar meanings as before.

In the following MWE, `hyperref` creates sectional bookmarks for every unstarred heading up to `secnumdepth` and only the numbered, unstarred versions show up in the ToC. The starred versions, removed from the ToC by default, are included using some variation of `\...pdfbookmark`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{FIRST PART}
\chapter{First chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2]
\section*{Second section} \currentpdfbookmark{Second section}{ch:1:sec:2} \lipsum[3]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[4]
\subsection{First subsection} \lipsum[5]
\subpdfbookmark{First subsubsection}{ch:1:sec:3:ssec:1:sssec:1}\subsubsection{First subsubsection} \lipsum[6]
\currentpdfbookmark{Second subsubsection}{ch:1:sec:3:ssec:1:sssec:2} \subsubsection*{Second subsubsection} \lipsum[7]
\subsection{Second subsection} \lipsum[8]
\currentpdfbookmark{Third subsection}{ch:1:sec:3:ssec:3} \subsection*{Third subsection} \lipsum[9]
\pdfbookmark[2]{Fourth subsection}{ch:1:sec:3:ssec:4}\subsection*{Fourth subsection} \lipsum[10]
\subsection{Fifth subsection} \lipsum[11]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

For the inclusion of sectional numbers in the PDF bookmark panel, use the `bookmarksnumbered` option of `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

The above MWE will then produce:

[image]

<sup>*</sup> If not, the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) provides similar, stand-alone functionality for inclusion of PDF bookmarks in your document. In fact, `hyperref` suggests using it as improved bookmark organization.

Comment: Actually, this answers one of my questions; the \currentpdfbookmark command is the key to solving the problem of unnumbered sections not being displayed as bookmarks. Still trying to figure out though how to get the generated bookmark names for the (numbered) sections to include the appropriate number as part of the text

Comment: @3Sphere: I just updated the answer to show how to include the sectional numbering - use the `bookmarksnumbered` option of `hyperref`.

Comment: If you dislike having the section name in the code twice, you can use e.g. `\subsection*{A}\pdfbookmark[2]{\GetTitleStringResult}{label}`.