# Displaying sections in table of contents/side bar of pdf viewer

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, bookmarks

I wasn't sure how to search for this as I'm not sure what's it's called. Apologies if this is a duplicate though.

Sometimes when I open a PDF, the sidebar will list the table of contents and I'll be able to jump to a section or subsection by click on it's title in the pdf viewer's sidebar. Example: 
[image: example]

Other times, when I open up a long pdf, all I see in the sidebar are just the pages, listed in order, but with no other sort of organization. Non-example:

[image: non-example]

> How do I construct my paper so that it works like the first example?

Comment: the `hyperref` package is the usual way of getting such things in latex, it has several commands for controlling this (bookmarks) but also by default the standard `\(sub)section` commands will add entries to the hierarchical bookmark pane.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So do I need hyperref to use \subsection?

Comment: @AlanH no; you need [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (or [`bookmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)) to create the bookmarks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Then if I use \section or \subsection, it should create a bookmark automatically, right?

Comment: If you are using one of the two packages I mentioned, yes.

Comment: A detailed answer for getting the numbered bookmarks like in the first screenshot, try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35430/79995

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to load

```
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels,bookmarks,hyperindex,hyperfigures]{hyperref}.
```

It should be the last package to be loaded (just to be sure it doesn't mix with other packages).

Although, according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106161/27833) pdftex could be not necessarily loaded.

Comment: Not *all* packages should be loaded before `hyperref`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you are right, but since I'm not sure what packages the OP is using, it was safer to just say "load it last"

Answer (score 1):

For me, including the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package as suggested by MarioS.E. above *only* generated the table of contents in the PDF viewer sidebar when I included a table of contents in the document using `\tableofcontents`. Without generating an actual table of contents in the document, `hyperref` seems to just make links to figures and citations active.